# How to achieve Single Sign On for my scenario?

Tags: spring-mvc, authentication, single-sign-on, cas, shiro

I have three web applications which are App1, App2 and App3 developed in SpringMVC and Apache Shiro framework.

- App1: App1 has own users and roles
- App2: App2 has own users and roles

App1 and App2 has different users and roles.

- App3: App3 doesn’t have own users and roles, it is common application
  for both App1 and App2

### My scenario:

1. If one user logged in App1 and the user should be able to view App3
   with his roles and permission. At the same time the user should not
   able to view App2.
2. If one user logged in App2 and the user should be able to view App3
   with his roles and permission. At the same time the user should not
   able to view App1.

How to achieve this? Please give me your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The SPs cannot control the permission. You need set the roles and permission on IdP. When SP send SAML request to the IdP, the IdP will response the SP whether the user can access the SP currently.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding CAS only authenticates users and grants access to your casified application. Anything further to do with role access for each authenticated user has to do with your respective application and CAS is out of picture at the point in time.

Link Reference:
https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/protocol/CAS-Protocol.html

Snippet:

> The CAS server is responsible for authenticating users and granting
>   accesses to applications

In your scenario, I would think of building some kind of a service to authorize based on roles in your respective application.